# Onsen-ui add new tab to ons-tabbar

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm using onsen ui for my app.

```
 <ons-tabbar position="top" animation="fade" id="tabsLayout">

 </ons-tabbar>
```

Is possible to add tab-item with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that works fine. Just append it to the element with the class name "tab-bar" and don't forget to run `ons.compile()` on the element:

```
var $tab = $('<ons-tab page="home.html" label="Label" active="true"></ons-tab>');
$('.tab-bar').append($tab);
ons.compile($tab[0]);
```

I used jQuery to make creating the element a bit more easily. You can of course use `document.createElement()` and `el.appendChild()` instead if you aren't using jQuery.